# How to find bounding box of non white area of image with OpenCV Python

Tags: bounding-box, opencv, python

I have an image with a white border.  I want to find the bounding box of the non-border part.  I also have some images with a black border and need to do the same for them but for black.   I do not want to crop the image just get the origin and size of the bounding box and then draw a green rectangle around it.

[image: Stars]
[image: Bounding Box around non-white border]

Comment: Threshold on white and then invert. See cv2.threshold() and then invert = 255 - image or use cv2.bitwise_not()

Comment: But how do I find the bounding box origin/size from that?

Comment: Once you  have the binary image, you can find contours (cv2.findContours), then get the bounding box from the contours (cv2.boundingRect). See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/ and search Google for examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get the threshold image and calculate the bounding box coordinates from it:

```py
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gry,(3,3), 0)
th = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
coords = cv2.findNonZero(th)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(coords)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
```

Also, you can use 'cv2.THRESH_BINARY' instead of 'cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV' in the threshold section for finding the black border bounding box.